# Visual Studio 2015 Navigation MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, wcf

I was wondering if anyone knew of a good way to help me navigate a MVC ASP.Net solution.

Here is the set up:
I have a MVC ASP.Net Web Project that calls and references a WCF service.

Is there a easy way to link the javascript ajax calls that call the controller actions, and then from the controller to the WCF service.

VS is great about the goto definition but that breaks down with both javascript and WCF.

Is there a way to add a comment that you can click on that will take you a method in a certain class?

Comment: I always use the <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>,(comma)</kbd> shortcut when I have my cursor on the name of the c# method I want to browse to as a shortcut.

Comment: Do you want to post this as a answer! This is exactly what I am looking for. I can for example put a comment in the javascript \\AdminControler.SaveSomething and have it go right to that method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I always use the <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>,(comma)</kbd> shortcut when I have my cursor on the name of the c# method I want to browse to as a shortcut. This brings up the [Navigate To](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mvpawardprogram/2013/10/22/visual-studio-2013-navigate-to-improvements/) UI element, and shows you methods, fields, properties, and files that match the item under the cursor, or highlighted text.